# Possibilities for GCD?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose a and b are positive integers and x and y are integers such that ax+by = 65. What are the possibilities for gcd(a,b)?

By Bezout's Lemma any number of the form $ax + by$ is a multiple of the $d = \gcd(a, b)$.

Thus $d|65$, so the possibilities are $d = \{1, 5, 13, 65\}$. Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct, but you need to give pairs $(a,b)$ to show that all these possibilities for $d$ are indeed possible, or at least an argument why those pairs exist. 
Your proof only shows that all $d$ such that $d \not\in \{1,5,13,65\}$ don't satisfy. You also need to show that all $d$ such that $d \in \{1,5,13,65\}$ do, in fact, satisfy.

Comment: You mean, he needs to prove integers $a$ and $b$ exist with $\gcd(a,b)=k$? I would assume that it is known that for any positive integer $k$ integers $a$ and $b$ exist with $\gcd(a,b)=k$.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Yeah, you can assume that, but currently, his proof only shows that all $d$ such that $d \not\in \{1,5,13,65\}$ don't satisfy. You also need to show that all $d$ such that $d \in \{1,5,13,65\}$ do, in fact, satisfy.

Comment: It's not clear that the OP needs to additionally show that (due to the mathematical imprecision of the phrase involving "possibilities").

Comment: So I just brute force it now?

Comment: Yes, you can just take $(66,1)$, $(70,5)$, $(78,13)$ and $(130,65)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct.

If $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $n$ then there exists $x$ and $y$ with $ax+by=n$.

On the other hand, $\gcd(a,b)$ clearly divides $ax+by$ for any $x,y\in \mathbb Z$.